# Return focus to previous input after viewing modal

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an Angular application where I have a form with many inputs to fill out. While filling out the form, the user has an option to open a modal where they can enter notes by using a hotkey. What I am trying to do, is return the focus onto the previously focused input field once the user closes the modal.

As of now, I have what appears to be a working solution, but it seems very tedious and I'm unsure if this is the best way to do something like this.

On every single `input` field, I have a `(focus)` that sets a variable `prevFocus` to the input name. For example:

```
<input
  (focus)="prevFocus = 'customerName'"
  name="customerName"
  placeholder="Name"
  type="text"
  pInputText
  formControlName="customerName"
/>
```

This variable is stored, and when the user closes the modal, a function is called:

```
closed() {
  console.log(this.prevFocus);
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setFocus(`${this.prevFocus}`);
  });
}

setFocus(name) {
  const ele = this.form.nativeElement[name];
  if (ele) {
    ele.focus();
  }
}
```

The `setTimeout()` is used to make sure the input is filled after the component is loaded.

My question, is that I have over 80 input fields, and this seems tedious to do for every single input. But, is this the best way to approach? Has anyone done something similar where the focus will return after doing a different action or temporary losing focus?

[HERE is a Stackblitz I created to show what I am looking at](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-return-input-focus?file=src/app/app.component.ts). There are a few functions such as for the hotkey shortcut, and I am using the PrimeNG library. The library and other functions don't relate to the specific concern of returning to the previously focused input, but they are included to get the full user experience: Begin filling out form with input in focus → use hotkey (alt + a) to open modal → click `esc` or click the x to close → input focus returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `document.activeElement` to save the current focusing element and call `activeElement.focus()`after closing the modal

create a type for focusable elements

```
export type FocusableElement = HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement // add more if you wan
```

and the code for setting activeElement

```
activeElement:FocusableElement

constructor(
    private eventManager: EventManager,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any
  ) {
    this.addShortcut({ keys: 'alt.a' }).subscribe(() => {
      this.activeElement = document.activeElement as  FocusableElement;
      this.showModalDialog();
    });
  }

closed() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(this.activeElement){
      this.activeElement.focus()
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. I really appreciate the solution! Everything working as expected.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to set input elements using the document...? For example, to set focus on the notes input once the modal is open. The document.activeElement log is not helpful (nor are the docs)

Comment: let me see. Can you attach your demo link again? it's broken

Comment: Went ahead and updated the link, sorry about that. Basically just wondering how I can set focus on other inputs. Apart from .getElementById().focus() I am not sure.. Using the method you provided it is easy to get previous focused link, but in case I want to set new focus. Thank you

Comment: There're many ways to do that. You can mark the element by `ViewChild` and set focus when you want, or create a `Directive` if you want to reuse it in many places. in your case. you can simply use `autofocus`(HTML attribute) to focus an element when it initializes your code will look like this `<input name="notes" type="text" *ngIf="displayModal" pInputText autofocus />`

Answer (score 0):

If (as seen on the stackblitz example) all the controls are more or less the same with only a few variations between them, you can instead create an array of objects with properties needed; eg:

```
     const formList= [
       { name: "customerAddress"
        placeholder: "Address"
        type: "text"
        name: "customerAddress"
        formControlName: "customerAddress"}
    ]
```

Then loop through it in the HTML set it only once:

```
 <form #form>
        <ng-container *ngFor="formItem of formList">
              <input
                (focus)="prevFocus = formItem.name"
                [name]=formItem.name
                [placeholder]=formItem.placeholder
                [type]=formItem.placeholder
                pInputText
                [formControlName]=formItem.formControlName
              />
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

In the case you might have other elements except input you can use Case statement based on the `type` property to create different elements based on the type. This will also allow you to flexibly add any new field in the array and will automatically be created.

Comment: PS: The answer by @Tanuwo seems to be better for the current scenario.